# How do I realize a Full Adder without the use of AND gates?

Tags: logic, xor

So. A normal full adder that have 3 inputs
`A, B, Ci (carry in)` and 2 outputs `S (Sum), Co (Carry-out)`. After doing truthtable and K-map we get the function for S as: `S = A ⊻ B ⊻ Ci` and the function for Co as: `AB ∨ Ci(A ⊻ B)`
Now when we are realizing this in gate-form S is pretty simple. 2 XOR gates where one with inputs A and B are connected to a second one. However, we are supposed to NOT use AND gates in this realization and in the Co function I can't solve on how to design the circuit. We are not told we can't use NAND gates, so that is a possibility. Is that the only way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOR` gates as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/full-adder-in-digital-logic/):

[image]